# Find the Average Velocity and the Instantaneous Velocity

Tags: calculus

Find the average velocity of an object whose position is given by:

$$s(t)=\frac{13}{t+2}$$

Using the following intervals:

i.[11,12]

ii. [11, 11.1]

iii. [11, 11.001]

iv. [11, 1.00001]

Then guess the value of the instantaneous velocity at *t*=11

I've look at a couple of examples and I'm still not completely understanding how to solve it.  Do I find the average between all of the intervals answers?

Please Help!!!

Comment: Yes, you're supposed to find the average velocity on each interval. Do you have a formula for the average velocity over an interval? Can you apply it here? Also, is that $\frac{13}{t+2}$ or $\frac{13}{t}+2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're supposed to find the average velocity over each interval.  In this case, we have
$$
s(t)=\frac{13}{t+2}
$$
(if you mean something else, please say so).  To find the average velocity over an interval $[t_1,t_2]$, the formula is
$$
v=\frac{s(t_2)-s(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}
$$
So, for i) we get
$$
v = \frac{\frac{13}{12+2}-\frac{13}{11+2}}{12-11}\approx-0.0714
$$
Can you figure out the rest?

Comment: ok so i got the average. (I believe it is -0.0753). But do I do anything with the instantaneous velocity of t=11?

Comment: Ok, nevermind I was able to get the answer (which is -0.0603).  Thanks for the help.

Comment: For the instantaneous velocity you're just supposed to guess. If the function is $\frac{13}{t+2}$, then you should get an instantaneous velocity of about $-0.0769$ (which is $\frac1{13}$ in fact) at $t=11$.  If your answers didn't get progressively closer to that number, then one of us did something wrong